# Was ist die Herkunft von Schwof?

Tags: etymology

Ich kenne das Wort *Schwof* nur mündlich als veraltete Bezeichnung für eine Tanzveranstaltung. Was ist die Herkunft dieses Wortes?

Answer (score 6):

Laut dem Duden Herkunftswörterbuch (2. Auflage) wurde die Bezeichnung ab dem 19. Jahrhundert von Studenten verwendet und geht zurück auf die ostmitteldeutsche Form von "Schweif" (ab dem 14. Jahrhundert vor allem mit der Hauptbedeutung *Schwanz*). *Schweif* ist eine Substantivierung des Verbes "schweifen", welches eine *schwingende Bewegung* bezeichnet. Entsprechend gibt es auch das Verb *schwofen* ("sich hin und her bewegen").